# SweetAlert2 - if one button, it gets highlighted as soon as modal opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I just changed from using SweetAlert to SweetAlert 2. It took a while to get around but I achieved what I wanted except one thing.

As soon as I open the modal, if there is 1 button and no inputs, etc., the button gets highlighted like this:

[image]

Is there a way to stop it getting highlighted before any interaction is made button?

---

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this code into your css

```
button.swal2-styled {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below snippet where On before open Sweetalert there is a function  which will called and there you can do some stuff you needed like stop highlighting buttons or something else.

For more information and more events like OnClose etc.. please find this [Link](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) and find **CONFIGURATION** section

I hope it'll help you.

```js
swal({
  title: 'Alert!',
  text: 'Heyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
  onOpen:OnOpenFunction(),
  confirmButtonClass:"btn-disable",
  buttonsStyling:true
})

function OnOpenFunction()
{
     //Stop Highlighting your button etc..
  //alert("On Before Open Model Event!!!!!");
}
```

```css
.btn-disable
        {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none;
        outline: none;
        /*Button disabled - CSS color class*/
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: #ffffff;

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.3.2/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.3.2/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: But in the snippet, it's still getting selected :( How can I disable it..

Comment: Please find updated snippet button is getting disabled now just make a css class **btn-disable** and apply on **confirmButtonClass**

Comment: Maybe it's from my laptop/browser or something else.. The glitch still occurs on my end.. Maybe it's from my end, or maybe it's just a glitch. Thanks though

Comment: i have checked on Chrome **50.0.2661.102** and mozilla **43.0.1**

Comment: I have checked on Chrome v55. I am adding the screenshot in OP,

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned by @Badal is working but it relies on internal plugin classes which is bad.

The better solution is to use the `confirmButtonClass` option:

```
.no-outline {
  outline: none;
}
```

And then pass that class to the `confirmButtonClass` option:

```
swal({
  ...
  confirmButtonClass: 'no-outline',
  ...
})
```